# How can I avoid rewriting construction logic present in initializer lists?

Tags: c++

Suppose I have a CPP class like

```
 class A {
    A() :
     max_(0),
     num_(0),
     sum_(0),
     sum_squares_(0) {}

    void Clear() {
      min_ = bucketMapper.LastValue();
      max_ = 0;
      num_ = 0;
      sum_ = 0;
      sum_squares_ = 0;
    }

    void SomethingElse {}
}
```

I have the initialization code in the constructor and in Clear, is there a way I can avoid having the same code twice.

Comment: Sounds to me, like the bad old helper-function is needed^^... (meaning: get rid of the init-list and call Clear() inside ur ctor)

Comment: You can call `Clear` from your constructor too.

Comment: @LukeB. not quite.  clear does more! looks like he needs to write another function that can be shared between the constructor and clear.

Comment: This is not the same code, the two code sections do completely different things. For example, the constructor creates a variable called `sum_` with an initial value of zero. `Clear` sets the value of an existing variable called `sum_` to zero.

Comment: This issue when it came about rewriting similar constructors was the reason delegating constructors were proposed, however it does not help out in your case.

Comment: Actually I find that this happens relatively often...

Comment: If you write this sort of code a lot, you might want to rethink your general style. Usually you should try to keep an object's lifetime as short as possible. Dispose with an object when you're done with it, and make a new one when you need one. Something like `clear()` smells off.

Comment: @KerrekSB, Is that why the container classes have *clear*? :p

Comment: @DavidSchwartz in both places the variable is already there, the constructor is not "creating" it, its merely setting its value.

Comment: @thang You're right, I missed the min_ there.

Comment: @LukeB.: Not true. If that was true, you could never initialize a member reference.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz isn't 'initializing' different from 'creating'?

Comment: @LukeB.: Yes. Initializing is the last step in creating. Regardless, they do completely different things. (For example, if this was an instance of the class `Foo`, one might call `Foo::Foo(0)` and the other `Foo::operator=(0)`, which can have completely different semantics. Each performs an operation that is prohibited in the other's context. You can't call a constructor on a constructed object. You can't assign a value to an unconstructed object.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz You're right, my bad.

Comment: Sounds like you want to `swap`!

Comment: @thang: Container-`clear()`s usually *destroy elements*, just like I recommended. They don't *reassign* elements.

Comment: @KerrekSB, clear re-assigns member variables after it deletes memory that was allocated.  destructor also destroy elements, why not just tell people to destroy a list everytime you need to clear it instead of calling clear?  effectively, clear destroys and re-initializes.  consider an implementation of the list that uses a doubly linked list and a count to keep track of size.  clear would delete all the elements AND set head, tail, and count to 0.  the second operation is done in the constructor as well.  the general guideline of destroy and recreate when you want to clear doesn't always hold.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need multiple constructors which call the same logic, you should write all of it within a `Clear` or `Reset` function and call it from each constructor.

Initializer list is REQUIRED in reasonably few cases, and besides those, it is just preferred for efficiency.

It is required for:

- Base classes (unless default no argument constructor is present and you're OK in calling it)
- Member that are references
- `const` members

Answer (score 2):

This original code,

```
 class A {
    A() :
     max_(0),
     num_(0),
     sum_(0),
     sum_squares_(0) {}

    void Clear() {
      min_ = bucketMapper.LastValue();
      max_ = 0;
      num_ = 0;
      sum_ = 0;
      sum_squares_ = 0;
    }

    void SomethingElse {}
}
```

would not compile, due to missing argument list and semicolon, and would fail to initialize `min_` in the default constructor, leaving that member with an **indeterminate value**, and everything in there is **inaccessible**.

Do you really want to give `min_` a different, new value in `Clear`?

If not then just assign a default-constructed instance:

```
*this = A();
```

Calling `Clear` from the constructor is not a good idea in general, mainly because it is very similar to an ungood habit of expressing construction in terms of assignment, and so might entice you into doing that.

For a more general solution, factor out the pure data:

```
namespace detail {
    struct A_Data
    {
        double min_;
        double max_;
        int    num_;
        double sum_;
    };
}  // namespace detail

class A
    : private detail::A_Data
{
public:    
    A(): detail::A_Data() {}

    void clear()
    {
        *this = A();
        min_ = bucketMapper.LastValue();
    }

    void somethingElse() {}
};
```

But most likely

```
*this = A();
```

will do as a solution for your needs.

---

-1 for not real code. Please do post real code in future questions. Not sort of like.